# Express generator error while running "SET DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start" command

Tags: javascript, express, cmd, command

[image]

I created express application using command "npx express-generator --view=ejs myapp", after creating application it asked me to run two commands "npm install" that ran successfully but other command "SET DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start" giving me the error as shown in image. I did search for the same but didnt find solution , so posting here. Please help

Answer (score 1):

For Windows PowerShell, use this command: $env:DEBUG='myapp:*'; npm start

Here is the complete link: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you ran that code in full.

Run:

```bash
SET DEBUG=myapp:*
```

Then run:

```bash
npm start
```